# Can not use .json information

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a heads up I'm completely new to the coding scene and I'm having some issues using a json file
I've got the json to open using

```
json_queue = json.load(open('customer.json'))
```

but I just cant find the right code that allows me to make use of the info on the json. I think its because the json is an array not an object (probably completely wrong) My json currently looks like this

```
[
  ["James", "VW"],
  ["Katherine", "BMW"],
  ["Deborah", "renault"],
  ["Marguerite", "ford"],
  ["Kenneth", "VW"],
  ["Ronald", "Mercedes"],
  ["Donald", "BMW"],
  ["Al", "vauxhall"],
  ["Max", "porsche"],
  ["Carlos", "BMW"],
  ["Barry", "ford"],
  ["Donald", "renault"]
]
```

What I'm trying to do is take the persons name and the car type they are looking for and compare it too another json file that has the stock of cars in a shop but I'm currently stuck as to how I get python to actually use the information in that json.

I think I might of over explained my problem. My issue is that I am just starting a project using .json files and I can get python to open the file, but then I am unsure of how to get python to read that "James" wants a "VW" and then to go check the stock json to check if it is in stock. The stock json looks like this.

```
{
    "VW": 4,
    "BMW": 2,
    "renault": 0,
    "ford": 1,
    "mercedes": 2,
    "vauxhall": 1,
    "porsche": 0,
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what problem are you having? Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Your code and sample json work for me - what errors are you getting/problems you are hitting?

Comment: It's a list of lists of strings. `json_queue[0][0]` is `"James"` etc. Do you know how to write loops and use lists?

Comment: After you use `json.load`, you do not have any JSON anymore, it's regular Python dicts and lists.

Comment: Removed the `json` tag as it's actually totally unrelated - as Norrius mentions, what you have here is a plain python list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have after the `json.load()` call is a plain python list of lists:

```
whishlist = [
  ["James", "VW"],
  ["Katherine", "BMW"],
  ["Deborah", "renault"],
  ["Marguerite", "ford"],
  ["Kenneth", "VW"],
  ["Ronald", "Mercedes"],
  ["Donald", "BMW"],
  ["Al", "vauxhall"],
  ["Max", "porsche"],
  ["Carlos", "BMW"],
  ["Barry", "ford"],
  ["Donald", "renault"]
]
```

where each sublist is a ,  pair. You can iterate over this list:

```
for name, car in whishlist:
    print("name : {} - car : {}".format(name, car))
```

Now with your "other json file", what you have is a dict:

```
stock = {
  "VW": 4,
  "BMW": 2,
  "renault": 0,
  "ford": 1,
  "mercedes": 2,
  "vauxhall": 1,
  "porsche": 0,
  }
```

so all you have to do is to iterate over the `whishlist` list, check whether the car is in stock and print (or do anything else) the result:

```
for name, car in whishlist:
    in_stock = stock.get(car, 0)
    print("for {} : car {} in stock : {}".format(name, car, in_stock))




for James : car VW in stock : 4
for Katherine : car BMW in stock : 2
for Deborah : car renault in stock : 0
for Marguerite : car ford in stock : 1
for Kenneth : car VW in stock : 4
for Ronald : car Mercedes in stock : 0
for Donald : car BMW in stock : 2
for Al : car vauxhall in stock : 1
for Max : car porsche in stock : 0
for Carlos : car BMW in stock : 2
for Barry : car ford in stock : 1
for Donald : car renault in stock : 0
```